# Problema con Android Studio, no acaba de arracncar un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

perdon por la molestia, pero me gustaria que me ayudaran con un problema que me ocurre en Android Studio. El tema en cuestion es que no me acaba de arrancar un fragment cuando pulso al boton en donde tengo programado que vaya. Les muestro una captura
[image: introducir la descripción]

Se me queda cargando en este estado. El codigo en cuestion creo que es correcto:

MainFragment:

````
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomNav: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_menu)

        bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_list -> {
                    loadFragment(ListFragment())
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }

        private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment){
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }



    }```






Al pulsar el boton home, tendria que inflar el fragment, lo que me llevaria  al fragment en cuestion, que contendria un RecyclerView en cuestion. Si quiere, y para guiarles mejor, les puedo pasar el xml de los layout en cueston para ver si hay tengo un fallo
Gracias por su ayuda y perdonen mi ineptitud.
````

Comment: agrega activity_main.xml

Comment: te sugiero agregar más información por favor,. revisa [ask], saludos.